# Why type cast a variable on its own line in C

Tags: c, casting

I encountered a function like this in [this demo of the libomemo library](https://github.com/gkdr/libomemo/blob/master/test/test_crypto.c):

```
int openssl_init(void ** state) {
  (void) state;

  // call another initialization function

  return 0;
}
```

I'm confused about the line `(void) state;`. I've seen similar lines of code all over the place, but I haven't been able to figure out what their purpose is. From what I understand about casts, that expression would return `state` converted to type `void`, but that value then goes unused.

Comment: That's to silence the (helpful) warning from some compilers that `state` is unused.

Comment: Thank you! I'll write that into an answer